# How to call rest api in loop using webclient and process all the responses in non-blocking way in java

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I am trying to use WebClient to call a rest api in a loop and process the response in non-blocking way.
Use case as follows, 
I need to call a rest api which returns data for at the most 7 days(startDate, endDate) but I receive input date range which can be any period such as 30 days, 6 months, 1 year etc and I need to call the api accordingly. 
 So e.g. if I get input date range of 30 days then I need to call the api 5 times to get required data.
**Lets say I need to find people with minimum loanAmount from 2022-09-01 to 2022-09-30.
I can use this api getLoanDetails(startDate, endDate) which accepts dates within 7 days period only. So I need to call this api 5 times (2022-09-01 to 2022-09-07, 2022-09-08 to 2022-09-14, 2022-09-15 to 2022-09-21, 2022-09-22 to 2022-09-28 and 2022-09-29 to 2022-09-30)**

I have created a list of dates of 7 days period from input date and running a loop over it and calling the api using WebClient in loop. I need to parse the json response, create Person objects from it and collect all persons with minimum loanAmount into a list(as there can be many with same loanAmount) 
`record Person(String name, BigDecimal loanAmount, LocalDate dateOfBirth) {}`

```
Flux<Person> findPeopleWithMinimumLoan(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {

  List<Pair<LocalDate>> dateList = getDates(startDate,endDate);
  for (Pair<LocalDate> periodToFindLoanDetails:dateList) { 
     Mono<List<Person>> personsWithMinimumLoanAmount = 
      callLoanApi(periodToFindLoanDetails.startDate(), periodToFindLoanDetails.endDate())
                    .map(this::findPeopleWithMinimumLoanAmount);

   **//TODO: Compare the result of all the loan api calls in a non blocking way and 
             return Flux<Person> or Mono<List<Person>>**
}

Mono<String> callLoanApi(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) { 
   return WebClient.create(apiURI)
                .get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.queryParam("aoi_key", apiKey)
                        .queryParam("start_date", startDate)
                        .queryParam("end_date", endDate).build())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
}

List<Person> findPeopleWithMinimumLoanAmount(String jsonFromLoanApi)
```

Now, I am struggling to use reactive data structures to process the response from all the api calls in a non-blocking way. I can for sure use block() and get result from each call and save it in some intermediate list and compare with next result and keep finding minimum until I got all the results. What is the ideal/better way to do this in a non-blocking and efficient way.
Thank you in advance for going through my question and apologies for long question or if question is not clear. Kindly let me know in comments and I can rectify. I have omitted some code as it is not relevant IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite broad question and a concrete answer depends on your environment. Assuming that calling the API you are consuming in this way is OK for the owner of the API and it can cope with the load.

Chain into the successful returned `Mono` with `subscribe`, `flatMap` or one of the `then` variations. If you want to execute a batch insert combine the `Mono`s and zip them together for instance with `zipWith` or manually.

This would result in something like (used Kotlin for brevity) for a simple use-case:

```
@Transactional
fun save(todo: Todo): Mono<Todo> {
  return todoRepository.save(mapToEntity(todo))
    .flatMap { saved -> updateTasks(todo, saved) }
}
```

https://github.com/AndreasKl/todo-reactive/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/todoservice/todo/TodoUseCases.kt#L36

Comment: Thank you for the answer Andreas. I am not looking to save the api result in database rather just process it on the fly and return the List<People> with minimum loan amount. What I need to do is call the rest api in a non-blocking way and then compare and merge results of all the api calls to find minimum.

Comment: @HrishikeshJoshi that is more or less what the above code does. It saves the passed in `Todo`s into a postgres database using Spring Data R2DBC and then saves the attached `Task`s. Substitute `Todo`s with `Person`.. and the initial `todoRepository.save` with your REST call. The pattern is always the same.. chain the reactive method calls together and `map` or `flatMap` the results.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, I have updated my code with Flux.parallel, flatMap and collect below which worked as expected. I was trying to merge the Mono's resulted from each api call and then process the result but chaining flatMap and collect did the trick. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around I found one possible solution as below,
Instead of using for loop to call loanApi multiple times I used Flux.parallel to do the same and the code looks like below

```
ParallelFlux<List<Person>> findPeopleWithMinimumLoan(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {

  List<Pair<LocalDate>> dateList = getDates(startDate,endDate);
  return Flux.fromIterable(dateList)
                .parallel()
                .flatMap(period -> callLoanApi(period.startDate(), period.endDate()))
                .map(this::parseJsonResponse)
                .flatMap(people -> Flux.fromIterable(people))
                        .collect(ArrayList::new, collectPeopleFromAllCalls);
}

Mono<String> callLoanApi(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) { 
   return WebClient.create(apiURI)
                .get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.queryParam("aoi_key", apiKey)
                        .queryParam("start_date", startDate)
                        .queryParam("end_date", endDate).build())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
}

List<Person> parseJsonResponse(String jsonFromLoanApi)
```